# Cannot modify nonability in PCGen

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pcgen

So in PCGen I have created a race but two of the stats are not editable.  It is because I based it on an animated object.  For the life of me I can't find out what defines a nonability.

Comment: Can you add the text based race definition to the question?